# Extracting X coordinate from numpy array

Tags: python, linux, numpy, raspberry-pi2, simplecv

I am extracting the x positions of 2 blobs via a live two camera stream. I can get the first x position no problem because it is given as a tuple, (ex = ...object at (455, 69)). The problem is I need the x position of the bottom left corner of the second blob but it returns as a numpy array and 'blob.x' does not work. How can I get the x position of the numpy array? Any help/guidance much appreciated.

I receive the following error:
    ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

```
from SimpleCV import *
def getscoreforrgb(rgb):
    return rgbmap[rgb]


mog1 = MOGSegmentation(history = 200, nMixtures = 5, backgroundRatio = 0.9, noiseSigma = 16, learningRate = 0.9)
mog0 = MOGSegmentation(history = 200, nMixtures = 5, backgroundRatio = 0.9, noiseSigma = 16, learningRate = 0.9)
cam1 = SimpleCV.Camera(1, {'width': 640, 'height': 480 })
cam0 = SimpleCV.Camera(0, {'width': 640, 'height': 480 })
pixcol = Image('/home/pi/Darts/score/scoreboardpy.png')



while True:

    frame1 = cam1.getImage()
    frame0 = cam0.getImage().flipHorizontal()
    mog1.addImage(frame1)
    mog0.addImage(frame0)
    segmentedImage1 = mog1.getSegmentedImage()
    segmentedImage0 = mog0.getSegmentedImage()


#### second blob below, does not print x position     

    blobs0 = segmentedImage0.findBlobs()
    if blobs0 is not None:
            blobs0.sortArea()
            blobs0[-1].draw(Color.BLUE, width=4)
            first_blob = blobs0[-1]
            bottomLeftCorner = second_blob.bottomLeftCorners()
            print bottomLeftCorner
            if bottomLeftCorner:
                    print bottomLeftCorner.x,
                    y = int(bottomLeftCorner.x)
                    print y * 2, 'Y'
                    y2 = y * 2

#### First blob below, code prints x position    

    blobs1 = segmentedImage1.findBlobs()
    if blobs1 is not None:
            blobs1.sortArea()
            blobs1[-1].draw(Color.RED, width=4)
            second_blob = blobs1[-1]
            if second_blob:
                    print second_blob.x, 
                    x = int(second_blob.x)
                    print x * 2, 'X'
                    x2 = x * 2


            colrgb =  pixcol[x2, y2]
            print colrgb
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: That's more than one line. Which exact line? It should say in the error message.

Comment: What is the point of that line?

Comment: Some old leftover code, it worked so I kept it. Without it it returns error y2 is not defined

Answer (score 1):

`y2` will not be defined if `blobs0 is None`, in which case you probably don't want to do anything anyway.

I suggest you put everything in a single `if` block:

```
blobs0 = segmentedImage0.findBlobs()
blobs1 = segmentedImage1.findBlobs()
if blobs0 is not None and blobs1 is not None:
    # all your code here
```

also you seem to be using `second_blob` instead of `first_blob` in the first block. And you should probably understand what your code is doing rather than blindly using some chunks of old code hoping it will work.

Comment: Thank you, I had just gotten it working and wasn't sure how to reorganize it. I've cleaned it up and the original problem persists, after 'print bottomLeftCorner.x' I get the error ' 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'x' '. Retrieving this x position is the overall goal

Comment: You need to know what object you are working with. Read the documentation of the functions you are using, it will tell you what type they are returning. Considering your error message, it looks like the coordinates are not returned as a structure or class with member `x` and `y` but as a `np.array`. My guess is that `x, y = bottomLeftCorner` should work.